# Simulating rnorm() using runif()

Tags: r, normalization

I am trying to 'simulate' rnorm() using only runif().

I don't know if I should do:

```
sqrt(-2*log(U1))*cos(U2)
```

or

```
sqrt(-2*log(U1))*sin(U2)
```

Where U1 is a runif(0,1) and  U2 runif(0,6.28)

I do not know if I should do it using cos or sin, or is it that I need to sample from  one and the other consecutively? What is the mathematical logic behind it?

Comment: You will want to investigate the Probability Integral Transform.

Comment: Because $\cos(U_2)$ is the horizontal coordinate of a point uniformly distributed on the unit circle and $\sin(U_2)$ is its vertical coordinate, notice that the symmetry of the circle under a switch of coordinates implies $\cos(U_2)$ and $\sin(U_2)$ are identically distributed.  Thus, your two methods are equivalent (assuming, anyway, that you replace "6.28" by $2\pi$).

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to use the [Box-Muller transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform).

The method is to use $U_1, U_2$ which are independently distribution Uniform(0,1). Then

$Z_0 = \sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)}\cos(2 \pi U_2) $

and

$Z_1 = \sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)} \sin(2 \pi U_2) $

are a pair of independent $N(0,1)$.

The derivation comes from using polar coordinates, but to be honest the exact steps escape me at the moment (see link if you are interested).

Answer (score 2):

Let $N_1,N_2$ be independent $N(0,1)$ random variates. $(N_1,N_2)$ defines a point in Cartesian coordinates. We transform to polar by

$$ N_1 = R \cos \theta$$
$$ N_2 = R \sin \theta$$

This transformation is one to one and has continuous derivatives. So we can derive the joint distribution $f_{R,\theta}(r,\theta)$ by using

$$f_{R,\theta}(r,\theta) = f_{N_1,N_2}(n_1,n_2)|J^{-1}|$$

where $J$ is the Jacobian of the transformation and

$$ J^{-1}(r,\theta )=
{\begin{bmatrix}{\dfrac {\partial n_1}{\partial r}}{\dfrac {\partial n_1}{\partial \theta }}\\{\dfrac {\partial n_2}{\partial r}}{\dfrac {\partial n_2}{\partial \theta }}\end{bmatrix}} 
= \begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta & -r\sin \theta \\\sin \theta & r\cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence $$ |J^{-1}| = r \cos^2 \theta + r \sin^2 \theta = r   $$

and

$$ f_{R,\theta}(r,\theta) = r \frac{1}{2\pi} e^{-\frac{1}{2}(n_1^2+n_2^2)} = \boxed{\frac{r}{2 \pi}e^{-\frac{1}{2}(r^2)}} \qquad 0 \leq \theta \leq 2 \pi, 0 \leq r \leq \infty \ $$

And we see $\theta \sim unif[0,2\pi]$ (since $f_{\Theta}(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi}$ ) and $R^2 \sim \exp(1/2)$

Hence, to simulate $\Theta$ we simply take $2 \pi U_2$ where $$U_2 \sim unif[0,1]$$ and to simulate $R$ we can take $$-2\ln U_1$$ where $U_1 \sim unif[0,1]$. ( to see why find the density of $X=-\ln U, U \sim  unif[0,1]$).

So, Box and Muller simply inverted $N_1= R \cos \theta$, $N_2= R \sin \theta$ and moved from $(R,\Theta)$ to $(N_1,N_2)$ by simulating $\Theta$ from  $2 \pi U_2$, and an independent $R$ from $ \sqrt{- 2 \ln U_1}$

explicitly

$$Z_0 = \sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)}\cos(2 \pi U_2)$$

$$Z_1 = \sqrt{-2 \ln(U_1)} \sin(2 \pi U_2)$$

And that is that is the mathematical logic behind it.

---

p.s. As I don't know whether it is clear through the mathematical justification (I believe it is, but you may have been lost in details),  note you need a pair of drawings from the uniform to get a pair of normals